# Valor por defecto de un Select con Formularios Reactivos

Tags: angular

Buen día.
Quizá mi pregunta suena tonta pero no encuentro como asignar un valor por defecto a un `<select>` usando formularios reactivos con Angular, es decir, puedo asignar un valor con `.setValue` pero no se como hacer que se muestre como la opción seleccionada por defecto cuando se detecta un cambio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te agrego un ejemplo de como lo hago. Primero hay que agregar la opcion vacía y la funcion change en el select.

```
      <select class='form-control' formControlName="section"
                    (change)="onSectionChange($event.target.value)">
              <option value="">Selecciona la sección.</option>
              <option *ngFor="let section of sections" [value]="section.idSeccion">
                {{section.nombre}}</option>
            </select>
```

Como ocupo un formulario reactivo, agrego el control para el select. en este caso como se inicializa con valor vacío, se selecciona por default la opción que tiene `value=""`.

```
     this.myForm = new  FormGroup({
         section: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
     });
```

ahora hay que agregar la funcion change aquí haria todo lo que necesitas cuando cambia de valor.

```
        onSectionChange(value) {
             //TO DO ...
        }
```

si el cambio que detectas viene de otro control, hay que setear el valor al select usa el setValue.

```
           this.myForm.get('section').setValue(this.sections[2].idSeccion);
```